# Populate a JCombobox from a text file

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, file-io, jcombobox

I have already seen an older question and the answer was a code like below, but if I use netbeans I have already designed my comboBox.  So I think (I am quite new in Java and netbeans as you imagine!) that the last line of the code should be changed and where do I insert this code?

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    String line = null;
    while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
        strings.add(line);
    }
}

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Error, file " + filePath + " didn't exist.");
}
finally {
    input.close();
}

String[] lineArray = strings.toArray(new String[]{});

JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(lineArray);
```

Comment: Unless this input is being obtained from the user, it will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource] which must be accessed by URL.

Answer (score 6):

1.these code lines are useless

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] lineArray = strings.toArray(new String[]{});
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(lineArray);
```

2.add a New Item to the [DefaultComboBoxModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7388965/714968) directly, Items could be sorted too

3.there could be [EDT issue read Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), use [SwingWorker for loading Items from File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can change an existing JComboBox's items by calling its `setModel` method.

For what it's worth, you may find the [Files.readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) method easier to use:

```
try {
    final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath),
        Charset.defaultCharset());

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            comboBox.setModel(
                new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(
                    lines.toArray(new String[0])));
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```