# JComboBox changinging other JComboBoxes (multiple times) error

Tags: java, jcombobox

need some help with ComboBoxes in Java. Looked through similar questions, found one slightly related, but not what im dealing with.

I need to load certain arrays into combo boxes depending on the items selected in the precious combo box:

think getting some procedure done at a medical center: Choose a procedure->get a list of doctors who do it, choose a doctor->get a list of available hours etc.

A single choice is working fine(whether it's "procedure->list of doctors", or "list of doctors->their working hours"), but doing more than a single one of those changes doesn't work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GUIbandymas extends JFrame {


String[] start={"Choose","Choice1", "Choice2"}; 
String[] Option1={"Choose","A1"};
    String[] Option2={"Choose","A2","A3"};
    String[] Option3={"Choose","a","b","c","d"};
    String[] Option4={"Choose","1","2","3","4"};
    String[] Option5={"Choose","I","II","III","IV"};



String[] pradinis={"Pasirinkite Laika"};
String[] p1={"Pasirinkite Gydytoja"};
 static double kainaR;
  static double kainaK;
   JComboBox<String> G=new JComboBox<String>(p1);
   JComboBox<String> proc;
  JComboBox<String> laikas=new JComboBox<String>(pradinis);
  JComboBox<String> minutes;
  JButton button = new JButton ("Registuotis");
 JLabel label = new JLabel("Moketi uz vizita");
 JLabel suma = new JLabel();



public GUIbandymas() throws Exception {


        setValueProc(start);
        frame();


}


public void frame()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500,300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(proc);
    panel.add(G);
    panel.add(laikas);
    panel.add(button);
    button.setEnabled(false);


    //panel.add(minutes);
    frame.add(panel);

    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(suma);


      proc.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(proc.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Choice1"))
        {
            setGyd(Option1);
        }
        if(proc.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Choice2"))
        {
            setGyd(Option2);
        }
    }   
});


G.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

            if(G.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("A1"))
            {
                setLaikas(Option3);
            }
            if(G.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("A2"))
            {
                setLaikas(Option4);
            }
            if(G.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("A3"))
            {
                setLaikas(Option5);
            }

    }

});//JComboBox



}

public void setGyd(String[] s)
{
    G.removeAllItems();
    for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
    {
        G.addItem(s[i]);
    }



}



public void setValueProc(String[] sarasas)
{
    proc=new JComboBox<String>(sarasas);

}

public void setLaikas(String[] sarasas)
{

    laikas.removeAllItems();
    for(int i=0; i<sarasas.length; i++)
    {
        laikas.addItem(sarasas[i]);
    }       
}


}
```

Im in a dire need of any suggestions and possible fixes, im inclined to think that it has something to do with action listeners, since methods do work, but im at a loss since i cant determine what is it.

EDITED: the actual code should work, seems like there is no unneeded things from other files left. 
NOTE: this is work with GUI, just launch it in you main() :)

Comment: It's much easier to answer this if you provide a working standalone example, i.e. something that can be executed and tested, instead of just code to inspect. You've also omitted the implmentations for setBoxNValue(..), which is rather crucial to the behaviour you want.

Comment: will edit my OP with the whole code, however because im using data read from files, ill submit predetermined arrays :)

Comment: If you comment the G.addActionListener... the code will (somewhat) work, same with proc.addActionListener....(albeit the JComboBox proc, will need to be initiated with values A1,A2 and A3 to check if it the selection works correctly, which it does) however both of them together...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't really like the if-else approach you're using, it should work just fine. I agree with rrirower's suggestion that you should look at using a data model instead. Especially if you get a lot of choices, since the code turns messy quite fast.

The problem with your code is that you run into `NullPointerException` when rebuilding the combobox items. The reason for this is that `G.actionPerformed()` is called when you remove/add items. After you have removed all items (before you start adding new ones), `G.getSelectedItem()` will return null.

If you code a little bit more defensively, then it works as expected:

```
    proc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object selectedItem = proc.getSelectedItem();
            if ("Choice1".equals(selectedItem)) {
                setGyd(Option1);
            }
            if ("Choice2".equals(selectedItem)) {
                setGyd(Option2);
            }
        }
    });
    G.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            Object selectedItem = G.getSelectedItem();
            if ("A1".equals(selectedItem)) {
                setLaikas(Option3);
            }
            if ("A2".equals(selectedItem)) {
                setLaikas(Option4);
            }
            if ("A3".equals(selectedItem)) {
                setLaikas(Option5);
            }
        }
    });//JComboBox
```

Instead of checking for null's, I just flipped the equals and skipped the unnecessary `toString()` (they are already strings, that's what you put in there).

Another thing, a pet peeve of mine, please follow the normal java code convention for all your class, field and method names. You're almost there, but `Option1` etc. should start with lowercase. `G` should probably have a more descriptive name, as well as start with lowercase.

Finally, I didn't understand why you both create a `JFrame` in the constructor *and* extend `JFrame` in your class. You should choose one or the other.

Comment: Thank you! I have already consulted obe of the lecturers at my uni about this and got some help with figuring out a dolution utilising DefaultComboBoxModel. Still, thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be using a data model for the combo box.  The data model controls the internal list of items.  Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387299/dynamically-adding-items-to-a-jcombobox) for more info.

Comment: researching ComboBoxModel already, thank you for the suggestion :)