# Overwriting JCombox values in runtime from uploaded file

Tags: java, arrays, swing, file, jcombobox

```java
for(int i = 0; i<total_lines; i+=3) {
    cnames[cindex] = currlist.get(i);
    cfactor[cindex] = currlist.get(i+1);
    csymbol[cindex] = currlist.get(i+2);
    //currdata.addElement(cnames[cindex]);
    combocurrency.addItem(cnames[cindex]);
    cindex++; 
}
combocurrency = new JComboBox<String>(cnames);
```

When the application first starts, the the `cnames` array loads string data from default file. But during runtime when i upload a new file, `cnames` values' are updated, but the `combocurrency` values remains the same in the application! How can i overwrite the combobox values by loading a new file during runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the MVC pattern here and work with a model. You can use `DefaultComboBoxModel` or implement your own if you need.
A good example is given here: [Dynamically adding items to a JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387299/dynamically-adding-items-to-a-jcombobox)

Answer (score 0):

Try to  clear the combobox of all entries using removeAllItems() before adding cnames